# How do I avoid cycles across two columns within a DataFrame to render a Sankey diagram with Google Charts?

Tags: python, pandas, google-visualization

I have a DataFrame with source and destination IPs, and bytes,

```
[ 1.2.3.4, 8.8.8.8, 123456 ]
...
[ 8.8.8.8, 1.2.3.4, 1234 ]
```

My problem is that I am using this DataFrame for a [JS visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey) which breaks if there is such a cycle. Like between 1.2.3.4 and 8.8.8.8.

> Note: Avoid cycles in your data: if A links to itself, or links to B
>   which links to C which links to A, your chart will not render

Is there a way to make sure that I remain uni-directional in the relationship? So in case 8.8.8.8 links back to 1.2.3.4 - and creates a cycle - I'd either skip it or swap the values. I am not sure if swapping is an option with Pandas.

I got myself a quick workaround by limiting it to the top 10 talkers, where a cycle is less likely. But it's incomplete of course.

```
vis_data += str(netflow_df.groupby(("dip","sip","bytes"), as_index=False).sum()
                .sort_values(by="bytes", ascending=False)
                .head(10)[["sip", "dip", "bytes"]]
                .values.tolist()
               )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having any extra information would something like this be sufficient? :

```
for index in range(df1):
    if df1[a] == df2[b]:

        if df1[b]  == df2[a]:
             df1.drop(df1.index[index])
    pass
```

Comment: No, this would check if at a given index column a is equal to column b. My problem is that once I register the relationship a -> b I cannot register b -> a.

Comment: That is what i thought so check if a has an equal in column b (so a->b) , then if the second df has b == a then they are both the same relationship  (b->a) and thus you drop that repeat but inverse ocurrence. and keep only a->b. I apologise if I'm wrong

Comment: I think you are right I just have a thinking issue. ;)